# Who performed the stunts for the fight scenes of The Alchemist in Vidocq?

Tags: stunts, vidocq

I recently watched *[Vidocq](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0164961/?ref_=nm_knf_i4)* and I found fascinating the Capoeira-like fighting style of The Alchemist.

Did a single person perform his fight choreography? Who did that part of the stunts? Was that a specific artist specialized in this interesting form of fighting and did he bring his own choerographic inspiration to the project? Or was it just a random stunt double performing predrafted fights?

I tried looking through the list of stunt people credited on IMDB, but it doesn't state whose stunts they did, and their IMDB profiles were similarly unenlightening. I'm hoping that perhaps the information was revealed in some other material that I haven't found.